# Deriving Thermodynamics equations confusion

Tags: physical-chemistry

Please explain:

I have taken up to Cal 3 so I understand deriving but I guess because of how it is used in context of this class I am not understanding. In the thermodynamics equation: ( as an example) what is the difference in using dU = C<sub>v</sub>dt VS. $\Delta$U=Cv$\Delta$T. This may come across as a stupid question but I just don't understand, maybe because I have not had much practice, but would I need to be deriving something? Another example, I was asked to derive the Maxwell-Boltzmann constant, but in the book it shows the derivation and its literally just plugging in different equations;however, when I say that I don't mean its like dx/dt = v and then I substitute in v for that part but rather substituting in full equations.

EDIT: I'm sorry my question seems unclear, but I am asking it to the best of my ability. I guess all I want to know is what deriving an equation in physical chemistry means. If I derive x^2 it is 2x. Well as I have seen, if I derive the RMS equation, instead of actually (dx/dt)'ing anything, I am just plugging in different parts of different equations. Pretty ridiculous I get down voted for asking a question, unclear or not. The whole purpose of this forum is to help communicate issues with one another, not be rude.

Comment: Well it seems I entirely misunderstood what you were asking and answered a different question. In light of this I think it's quite fair that others voted to close as unclear. I tried to guess what you meant but in truth, I shouldn't be forced to guess. Your new edit does help to clarify. And the problem with your thinking is: a *derivation* does not necessarily involve *derivatives*. It simply means manipulating the maths somehow to prove a theorem or result. In this respect it means exactly the same thing as a proof. See Wikipedia: [Formal proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_proof).

Comment: Furthermore the construction "If I derive $x^2$ it is $2x$" is quite uncommon and is, to the best of my knowledge, incorrect. Even though the *first derivative* of $x^2$ is $2x$, you don't *derive* $x^2$; you *differentiate* it to get $2x$. So, this is a terminology issue.

Comment: yes.. thank you! It is clear I just did not understand the difference between the two words. Thanks again. Also, so does the dU in the example I provided mean taking the derivative of U, or just what you said about infinitesimal change? @orthocresol

Comment: The derivative of U with respect to something else, say T, is (dU/dT). This may *loosely* be understood to be the same thing as a ratio of infinitesimal changes: the ratio of dU to dT when some process happens. It doesn't make sense to say "take the derivative of U": you need something to differentiate it with respect to, since a derivative has dU over d(something). When you "take the derivative of $x^2$" the implicit assumption is that you are taking it with respect to $x$ which is why dx is in the denominator: $$\frac{\mathrm{d}(x^2)}{\mathrm{d}x} = \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}( x^2) =2x$$

Answer (score 3):

$\mathrm{d}U = C_V\,\mathrm{d}T$ relates an infinitesimal change in temperature to an infinitesimal change in internal energy.

$\Delta U = C_V \Delta T$ relates a finite change in temperature to a finite change in internal energy.

To get from infinitesimal to finite you have to add up, or sum, a huge number of infinitesimal changes. This isn't done with a sum, but rather an integral (which acts like a sum for infinitesimal quantities) from an initial state to a final state. Since both $U$ and $T$ are state functions you can do this quite safely without worrying about intricacies of path functions.

$$\begin{align}
\mathrm{d}U &= C_V\,\mathrm{d}T \tag{1} \\
\int_\text{initial}^\text{final}\mathrm{d}U &= \int_\text{initial}^\text{final}C_V\,\mathrm{d}T \tag{2}
\end{align}$$

The limits of integration on the left are simply the initial internal energy and the final internal energy. You can call it $U_1$ and $U_2$ respectively. Likewise the limits of integration on the right are $T_1$ and $T_2$

$$\begin{align}
\int_{U_1}^{U_2}\mathrm{d}U &= \int_{T_1}^{T_2} C_V\,\mathrm{d}T \tag{3}
\end{align}$$

In general, $C_V$ is a function of $T$. However, to get to your desired equation, you have to assume that $C_V$ is independent of $T$ over the temperature range you are interested in, i.e $C_V$ is a constant. That allows you to take it out of the integral much like you would any other constant.

$$\begin{align}
\int_{U_1}^{U_2}\mathrm{d}U &= C_V\int_{T_1}^{T_2} \mathrm{d}T \tag{4} \\
U_2 - U_1 &= C_V(T_2 - T_1) \tag{5} \\
\Delta U &= C_V\Delta T \tag{6}
\end{align}$$

So, **yes**, there is a difference. For the finite change you made an extra assumption that $C_V$ doesn't vary over the temperature range. For the infinitesimal change the temperature range is infinitesimally small - hence $C_V$ cannot vary and the assumption is not necessary.